# Is it dangerous to consume 30 mg of Zinc (as Zinc Picolinate) per day?

Tags: supplement, zinc

I was looking at the information about [a zinc supplement product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00083B1DY). Its specifications show that each does contains 30 mg of Zinc (as Zinc Picolinate), and that this is 275% of the daily value. Since an adult may consume only about 10 mg of zinc per day, 30 mg of zinc sounds like poison. Am I misreading the meaning of "Zinc (as Zinc Picolinate)"? In the Q&A page someone says that the manufacturer confirmed that 30 mg is the zinc element. But I suspect if the person misunderstood the message from the manufacturer or is just trolling. A company would not sell poison?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much zinc per day is "too much"?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/22930/how-much-zinc-per-day-is-too-much)

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Office of Dietary Supplements of the US National Institutes of Health](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/Zinc-HealthProfessional/), the upper tolerable limit for Zinc is as follows:

> ###### Table 3: Tolerable Upper Intake Levels (ULs) for Zinc
>
> | Age | Male | Female | Pregnant | Lactating |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0–6 months | 4 mg | 4 mg |  |  |
> | 7–12 months | 5 mg | 5 mg |  |  |
> | 1–3 years | 7 mg | 7 mg |  |  |
> | 4–8 years | 12 mg | 12 mg |  |  |
> | 9–13 years | 23 mg | 23 mg |  |  |
> | 14–18 years | 34 mg | 34 mg | 34 mg | 34 mg |
> | 19+ years | 40 mg | 40 mg | 40 mg | 40 mg |

As the Office of Dietary Supplements notes, the tolerable upper intake level is the

> maximum daily intake unlikely to cause adverse health effects.

Thus, 30mg per day is a tolerable dose of zinc as defined by the NIH for males or females age 14 or older.

However, as noted by [timeskull](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/users/24872/timeskull) in the comments,  this daily intake must *also* include the zinc one receives from other dietary sources. One study from a few decades ago found the average zinc intake of US adults to be 13mg/day (Briefel *et al* 2000. PMID [10801945](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10801945/)). Thus, more than half of the US population would be exceeding the UL by taking a 30mg dose of elemental zinc daily.

Zinc toxicity is rare (Agnew and Slesinger 2022. NBKID [554548](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK554548/)). However, chronic doses of 100-150mg/day of elemental zinc have been reported in association with secondary copper defficiency (Plum *et al* 2010. PMCID [2872358](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2872358/)). Higher daily doses have been associated with gastrointestinal symptoms including anorexia, vomiting, and diarrhea ([2021 Merck Manual](https://www.merckmanuals.com/professional/nutritional-disorders/mineral-deficiency-and-toxicity/zinc-toxicity)).

###### As always, individuals should consult with their personal physician before starting any supplement or medication.

Comment: 30 mg in a daily supplement is tolerable as long as the zinc in your diet is < 10 mg. The CDC toxological profile for zinc cites "A typical Italian diet contains about 10.6 mg of dietary zinc per day, where 4.3 mg of zinc comes from meat and meat products (Lombardi-Boccia et al. 2003)." so supplementing that typical Italian diet would be slightly over the recommended limit.

Comment: @timeskull Great point, I've edited the answer. To be fair, most reports of toxicity seem to be in the 100+ mg/day range.